# Unable to connect to vpn using OpenVpn on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I just removed and installed openvpn again and now there's no option of openvpn here, which was here earlier:

[openvpn option not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYQyF.png)

Also I get following when I go into vpn setting:

[Error on vpn configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqBqg.png)

I am unable to connect to vpn.

I tried re installing openvpn with this command:

```
sudo apt install openvpn
```

and it says already installed to the latest version.
I also reinstalled network manager.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only, so OS/networking support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You can probably ask on [ubuntu.se] instead, but first I recommend taking [their tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) and checking out [their How to Ask page](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Ok one thing worked for me:
Run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

and now this:

```
nm-connection-editor
```

It will inform what other dependencies are missing. In my case, it told me to run this command:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-gnome
```

then I ran `sudo apt update` and `upgrade`, and vpn got connected.

The other issues are solved as well, I am still unable to access the internet but this might be other issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### Try NMCLI if you do not know!

The first step is to install all of them:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

If you don't use the 'nmcli' command, You need to say hello to that...

*Just all you need, is to import the VPN file by this command:*

```
nmcli c import type openvpn file file.ovpn
```

It's easy enough

Comment: I could not connect to internet to install it. So what I did was Downloaded network manager on  another device, copied to my machine and then installed it. Everything worked.